# get() keywords must be strings

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-import-export

I can't tell what is the problem, and where the problem is. I was able to upload files through django import export but now I am not able to do so. Here is my Traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py", line 52, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\Django\test projects\library manage\lib_system\Library-System\libman\import_export_views.py", line 227, in post
    result = resource.import_data(data_set, dry_run=True, collect_failed_rows=True, raise_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 741, in import_data
    return self.import_data_inner(dataset, dry_run, raise_errors, using_transactions, collect_failed_rows, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 788, in import_data_inner
    raise row_result.errors[-1].error
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 635, in import_row
    instance, new = self.get_or_init_instance(instance_loader, row)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 330, in get_or_init_instance
    instance = self.get_instance(instance_loader, row)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 323, in get_instance
    return instance_loader.get_instance(row)
  File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\import_export\instance_loaders.py", line 31, in get_instance
    return self.get_queryset().get(**params)
TypeError: get() keywords must be strings
```

This si the resource file

```
class ImportBooksResource(resources.ModelResource):
    def __init__(self, school_id,*args,**kwargs):
        super(ImportBooksResource,self).__init__()
        self.school_id = school_id
        self.fields["id"] = fields.Field(widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Books,'id'))
        self.fields['department'] = fields.Field(widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Departments, 'name'))
    def before_save_instance(self, instance, using_transactions, dry_run):
        instance.school_id = self.school_id
    def before_import_row(self, row, **kwargs):
        row['department'] = row['department'].lower()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Books
        fields = ('reg_no','book_name','book_detail','department')
        import_id_fields = ('id',)
        import_order = ('reg_no','book_name','book_detail','department')
```

Answer (score 1):

This line looks wrong:

```
self.fields["id"] = fields.Field(widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Books,'id'))
```

Remove this line and it should work.

Reason: You are declaring a field on a ModelResource subclass for `Books`, which points says that there is a FK relation to `Books`.  There shouldn't be an FK relationship to `Books` from `Books`.  You don't need to declare the `id` field because you are using `ModelResource`, hence the field should be available implicitly.

Comment: KeyError. When import_id_fields = (id, ). [<built in function id>] and import_id_fields = ("id",), keyerror at ('id')